# UIButton in Swift 2.2. How to add different target?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, swift2

I created button in code.

```
        let item = UIButton()
        item.setImage(UIImage(named: "Menu"), forState: .Normal)
        view.addSubview(item)
```

How can I add target from other VC?

I tried a lot of things, but it is not compiled.

Method menuButtonAction() from OtherClass

Errors:

```
        item.addTarget(otherClassVar, action: #selector(OtherClass.menuButtonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        item.addTarget(otherClassVar, action: #selector(OtherClass.menuButtonAction(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

that method call selector immediately:

```
        item.addTarget(otherClassVar, action: Selector(OtherClass.menuButtonAction()), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 3):

SWIFT 2.2 or newer:

```
yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TheClassName.runThis(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

I guess is obvious that the function you want to run must be implemented in the class you want to run it from. Hope is clear enough.

```
func runThis(sender: AnyObject) {
       // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set `menuButtonAction` as `static/class` selector, but as I think at fact it is instance method, since it is not marked by `static/class` keyword

Try this instead:

```
item.addTarget(otherClassVar, action: #selector(otherClassVar.menuButtonAction), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: I have prom to insert @objc

Comment: @IgorBizi If your `otherClassVar` have type `OtherClass`, properly initialized and `OtherClass` have method `func menuButtonAction(){}`, then my code _must_ work.

Comment: @IgorBizi also you should present more information when ask questions at this site. Members should not guessing about your declarations in answers.

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you.....

```
let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.RoundedRect) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 150)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:125/255.0, green: 125/255.0, blue: 125/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)//Highlighted here you can change state....
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

and then call the function....

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)

{
       print("welcome to swift 2.2")
}
```